Is there any way to tackle this error of module not found in Node.js In CMD
I am challenging issue in installing properly node,js for flutter
the issue is here :
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\All Rounder Pc\hello.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []

